# What's python's LOAD_FAST bytecode instruction fast at?

Tags: python

https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_FAST

I have been wondering, why is it specifically named fast and not just "load"?

What alternatives could be used instead that are "slower"?

When are these alternatives used?

Comment: The place it loads things _from_ is the "fast locals array". There doesn't exist any slower way to load things from the fast locals array. :)

Comment: just read https://tenthousandmeters.com/blog/python-behind-the-scenes-5-how-variables-are-implemented-in-cpython/

Answer (score 6):

All the `_FAST` opcodes take a variable index to access a local variable. This is fast because it's a simple index into an array rather than a name lookup, which might have to loop through multiple contexts.